# Modules over the unipotent subalgebra as direct summands of modules over a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a semisimple finite-dimensional Lie algebra over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb C$.  Let $\mathfrak n\subset\mathfrak g$ be the maximal unipotent subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$.  (E.g., for the algebra of all traceless $n\times n$ matrices $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C)$, the subalgebra $\mathfrak n$ is the Lie algebra of all strictly upper-triangular $n\times n$ matrices, with zeroes on the diagonal.)

Let $N$ be a finite-dimensional nilpotent $\mathfrak n$-module (i.e., an $\mathfrak n$-module in which all the elements of $\mathfrak n$ act by nilpotent linear operators).  Can I find a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak g$-module $M$ such that $N$ is a direct summand of the underlying $\mathfrak n$-module of $M$?  If not, can I find an infinite-dimensional $\mathfrak g$-module $M$ with the similar property (generally speaking)?

For $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$, the answer is positive.  In this case, $\mathfrak n$ is a one-dimensional abelian Lie algebra with a generator $x$, and finite-dimensional nilpotent $\mathfrak n$-modules are finite direct sums of the $k[x]$-modules $k[x]/(x^m)$, where $m\ge0$ are nonnegative integers.  The $\mathfrak n$-module $k[x]/(x^m)$ underlies the (unique) $m$-dimensional irreducible $\mathfrak g$-module.  So, in this case, every finite-dimensional nilpotent $\mathfrak n$-module admits an extension of its $\mathfrak n$-module structure to a $\mathfrak g$-module structure, and one can even have $M=N$.

Is the answer negative for semisimple Lie algebras $\mathfrak g$ of higher rank?

(My motivation is far away from the Lie algebra representation theory.  For reasons having to do with the theory(ies) of corings and bocses, I am looking for an associative ring $A$ with a subring $B$ having the following properties:

1. the ring $A$ has finite left global (homological) dimension;
2. the ring $A$ is a free (or faithfully projective, or at least faithfully flat) right $B$-module, preferably also a free (or faithfully projective) left $B$-module;
3. the full subcategory of all $B$-module direct summands of underlying $B$-modules of left $A$-modules is not closed under extensions in the abelian category $B\mathrm{-Mod}$.

It is easy to satisfy 1. and 2., not difficult to satisfy 1. and 3., and I know how to satisfy 2. and 3.  Looking for a way to satisfy all the three conditions, I came up with the idea of considering $A=U(\mathfrak g)$ and $B=U(\mathfrak n)$.  End of motivation.)

Comment: The answer is negative if you want finite dimensional representations. WLOG we may assume $N$ is indecomposable. Suppose there exists a $\mathfrak g$-module $M$ containing $N$ with the desired properties. We can decompose $M$ into a direct sum of irreducible $\mathfrak g$-modules. So we may assume $M$ is itself irreducible. Then as an $\mathfrak n$-module $M$ is indecomposable and is generated by a lowest weight vector in $M$. So $M = N$, and in particular $N$ is generated by a single element. But not all indecomposable finite dimensional $\mathfrak n$-module is generated by one element.

Comment: For example, take the $\mathfrak n$ in $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb C)$. Its acts on itself by adjoint action, and this is generated by at least two vectors. I suspect the infinite dimensional question also has a negative answer, but I'll have to think about it a little bit.

Comment: @QixianZhao Thank you!  This answers my question for finite-dimensional $\mathfrak g$-modules.  Now I am interested in the infinite-dimensional question.